# HTML/CSS table in table styling

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I've a table in the last cell in the last row of an other table.
The styling should be with rounded corners.

The "outer" table looks good, but the "inner" table has rounded cell-corners in every row - is it because it's in the last "outer" table row? How can I seperate the styling from the other table?

[image: Example Picture]

Here is the code:

```css
  body {
   margin: 30px;
  }
  
  table {
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0;
   min-width: 350px;
  }
  
  table tr th,
  table tr td {
   border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
   padding: 5px;
  }
  
  table tr th:first-child,
  table tr td:first-child {
   border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  }
  
  table tr th {
   background: #eee;
   border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
   text-align: left;
  }
  
  /* top-left border-radius */
  table tr:first-child th:first-child {
   border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  /* top-right border-radius */
  table tr:first-child th:last-child {
   border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  /* bottom-left border-radius */
  table tr:last-child td:first-child {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
   }
  
  /* bottom-right border-radius */
  table tr:last-child td:last-child {
   border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  }
```

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Ü1</th>
   <th>Ü2</th>
   <th>Ü3</th>
   <th>Ü4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>11</td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Ü1</th>
      <th>Ü2</th>
      <th>Ü3</th>
      <th>Ü4</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>13</td>
   <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>21</td>
   <td>22</td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Ü1</th>
      <th>Ü2</th>
      <th>Ü3</th>
      <th>Ü4</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>31</td>
   <td>32</td>
   <td>33</td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>reset</th>
      <th>item2</th>
      <th>item1</th>
      <th>item2</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: The problem here is that the table you marked in your screenshot, is itself in the _last_ table row of its parent - so a selector like `table tr:last-child td:first-child` applies to _all_ last table cells in the inner table, regardless of what _inner_ table row they are in.

Comment: You can easily fix this by using the child combinator - but then you have to switch `table` for `tbody` (because table rows are never direct children of the table element itself, but of either a table head, foot or body - tbody gets implicitly created, if it is not in the HTML.) Modify those last four rules to use selectors of the form `tbody > tr:first-child > th:first-child`, and it should work as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.It might solve your problem :)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 30px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0;
            min-width: 350px;
        }

        table tr th,
        table tr td {
            border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        table tr th:first-child,
        table tr td:first-child {
            border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
        }

        table tr th {
            background: #eee;
            border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
            text-align: left;
        }

        /* top-left border-radius */
        table tr:first-child th:first-child {
            border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        }

        /* top-right border-radius */
        table tr:first-child th:last-child {
            border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        }

        /* bottom-left border-radius */
        table table tr:last-child td:first-child {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
            }

        /* bottom-right border-radius */
        table table tr:last-child td:last-child {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        }
    </style>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Ü1</th>
            <th>Ü2</th>
            <th>Ü3</th>
            <th>Ü4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ü1</th>
                        <th>Ü2</th>
                        <th>Ü3</th>
                        <th>Ü4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ü1</th>
                        <th>Ü2</th>
                        <th>Ü3</th>
                        <th>Ü4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>reset</th>
                        <th>item2</th>
                        <th>item1</th>
                        <th>item2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **td** in front of  table tr:last-child td:first-child

```css
  body {
            margin: 30px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0;
            min-width: 350px;
        }

        table tr th,
        table tr td {
            border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        table tr th:first-child,
        table tr td:first-child {
            border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
        }

        table tr th {
            background: #eee;
            border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
            text-align: left;
        }

        /* top-left border-radius */
        table tr:first-child th:first-child {
            border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        }

        /* top-right border-radius */
        table tr:first-child th:last-child {
            border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        }

        /* bottom-left border-radius */
       td > table tr:last-child td:first-child {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
            }

        /* bottom-right border-radius */
       td > table tr:last-child td:last-child {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head> 

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Ü1</th>
            <th>Ü2</th>
            <th>Ü3</th>
            <th>Ü4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ü1</th>
                        <th>Ü2</th>
                        <th>Ü3</th>
                        <th>Ü4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ü1</th>
                        <th>Ü2</th>
                        <th>Ü3</th>
                        <th>Ü4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>reset</th>
                        <th>item2</th>
                        <th>item1</th>
                        <th>item2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                        <td>item1</td>
                        <td>item2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a "td" in front of **bottom-left border-radius css** and  **bottom-right border-radius**

Answer (score 1):

Just add `>` for target only first `th` or `td` will resolve your issue. Try this I hope it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

```
    /* top-left border-radius */
    table tr:first-child > th:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    }

    /* top-right border-radius */
    table tr:first-child > th:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }

    /* bottom-left border-radius */
    table tr:last-child > td:first-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        }

    /* bottom-right border-radius */
    table tr:last-child > td:last-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
```

```css
body {
   margin: 30px;
  }
  
  table {
   border-collapse: separate;
   border-spacing: 0;
   min-width: 350px;
  }
  
  table tr th,
  table tr td {
   border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
   padding: 5px;
  }
  
  table tr th:first-child,
  table tr td:first-child {
   border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  }
  
  table tr th {
   background: #eee;
   border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
   text-align: left;
  }
  
  /* top-left border-radius */
  table tr:first-child > th:first-child {
   border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  /* top-right border-radius */
  table tr:first-child > th:last-child {
   border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  /* bottom-left border-radius */
  table tr:last-child > td:first-child {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
   }
  
  /* bottom-right border-radius */
  table tr:last-child > td:last-child {
   border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Ü1</th>
   <th>Ü2</th>
   <th>Ü3</th>
   <th>Ü4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>11</td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Ü1</th>
      <th>Ü2</th>
      <th>Ü3</th>
      <th>Ü4</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>13</td>
   <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>21</td>
   <td>22</td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Ü1</th>
      <th>Ü2</th>
      <th>Ü3</th>
      <th>Ü4</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>31</td>
   <td>32</td>
   <td>33</td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>reset</th>
      <th>item2</th>
      <th>item1</th>
      <th>item2</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
      <td>item1</td>
      <td>item2</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

table tr:last-child td:first-child

Is the Problem.

The Last-Child of your tr has following css-rule:

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px
```

Rendering the leftbottom border-Radius to have 6px.

disabling that, will solve your Problem, but also disable the bottom-left border.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solutions!
They are working like a charm.

We thought it would be an easy solution :-)